# Getting non overlapping between two dates with Carbon

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, php-carbon

UseCase: Admin assigns tasks to People. Before we assign them we can see their tasks in a gantt chart. According to the task assign date and deadline, conflict days (overlap days) are generated between tasks.

[image]

I wrote this function to get overlapping dates between two dates. But now I need to get non overlapping days between two dates, below is the function I wrote.

```
$tasks = Assign_review_tasks::where('assigned_to', $employee)
                ->where('is_active', \Constants::$REVIEW_ACTIVE)
                ->whereNotNull('permit_id')->get();
            
            $obj['task'] = count($tasks);
            //  count($tasks));
            if (count($tasks) > 0) {
                if (count($tasks) > 1) {
                    $start_one = $tasks[count($tasks) - 1]->start_date;
                    $end_one = $tasks[count($tasks) - 1]->end_date;
                    $end_two = $tasks[count($tasks) - 2]->end_date;
                    $start_two = $tasks[count($tasks) - 2]->start_date;

                    if ($start_one <= $end_two && $end_one >= $start_two) { //If the dates overlap
                        $obj['day'] = Carbon::parse(min($end_one, $end_two))->diff(Carbon::parse(max($start_two, $start_one)))->days + 1; //return how many days overlap
                    } else {
                        $obj['day'] = 0;
                    }
                    // $arr[] = $obj;
                } else {
                    $obj['day'] = 0;
                }
            } else {
                $obj['day'] = 0;
            }
            $arr[] = $obj;
```

`start_date` and `end_date` are taken from database,

I tried modifying it to,

```
(Carbon::parse((min($end_one, $end_two))->add(Carbon::parse(max($start_two, $start_one))))->days)->diff(Carbon::parse(min($end_one, $end_two))->diff(Carbon::parse(max($start_two, $start_one)))->days + 1);
```

But it didn't work, in simple terms this is what I want,

**Non conflicting days = (end1-start1 + end2-start2)- Current overlapping days**

I'm having trouble translate this expression . Could you help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you put clear example of what you want to achieve ? Think like someone who dont know your code and use case

Answer (score 1):

before trying to reimplement complex stuff I recommend you take a look at [enhanced-period for Carbon](https://github.com/kylekatarnls/enhanced-period)

```
composer require cmixin/enhanced-period
```

`CarbonPeriod::diff` macro method is what I think you're looking for:

```
use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;
use Cmixin\EnhancedPeriod;

CarbonPeriod::mixin(EnhancedPeriod::class);

$a = CarbonPeriod::create('2018-01-01', '2018-01-31');
$b = CarbonPeriod::create('2018-02-10', '2018-02-20');
$c = CarbonPeriod::create('2018-02-11', '2018-03-31');

$current = CarbonPeriod::create('2018-01-20', '2018-03-15');

foreach ($current->diff($a, $b, $c) as $period) {
  foreach ($period as $day) {
    echo $day . "\n";
  }
}
```

This will output all the days that are in `$current` but not in any of the other periods. (E.g. non-conflicting days)